# How to calculate all the elements in X X^T in R?

Tags: r, matrix, product, matrix-multiplication

Let **X** be a matrix with n rows and p columns. I want to calculate all the p times p matrices obtained by multiplying the rows of X times the transposed of the same rows. This is, the first matrix is

```
X[1,]%*%t(X[1,])
```

I want to avoid a for loop, so I wonder how to obtain the n (p times p) matrices associated to

```
X[i,]%*%t(X[i,])
```

with a more direct command such as `apply` or `sweep`. Sorry, I just cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: `lapply(1:nrow(X), function(i) X[i,] %*% t(X[i,]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `crossprod` or `tcrossprod` for operations like that (see [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/crossprod)). In your case,

```r
lapply(1:nrow(X), function(i) tcrossprod(X[i,]))
```